# Silverlight Toolkit - Where is the AutoCompleteBox?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I just added the Silverlight 4 toolkit to my project via NuGet. (NuGet package "Silverlight Toolkit - All")

I can't find the AutoCompleteBox anywhere in the dlls added to my project. Where is it?

Things I've tried:

- I cracked open all the dlls it added
  to my project, and I don't see
  AutoCompleteBox in any of them.
- Looking at the [Silverlight Toolkit
  discussions](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic), I don't see anyone mentioning its removal.
- Looking at the [Silverlight Toolkit
  changeset history](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets), I don't see it
  being mentioned as removed.
- I browsed the source, and I *do* see AutoCompleteBox in there, but it get compiled into a dll System.Windows.Controls.Input.dll, but when I add the project in via NuGet, I don't get that dll, instead I get System.Windows.Controls.Input.**Toolkit**.dll

Where is the AutoCompleteBox in the Silverlight Toolkit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not in the Silveright Toolkit any more.  As of Silverlight 4 it moved to the SDK.  You should be able to drag the AutoCompleteBox from you toolbar to the designer and VS will add the reference to `System.Windows.Controls.Input.dll` for you.

Comment: Ha. I didn't realized it moved to the SDK. Thanks.